# VMware Player unable to start after upgrade linux kernel to latest version

Tags: vmware, vmware-player

VMware player is working properly on my computer before upgrading Linux kernel. After that, VMware player was unable to run and display error as below.

Error message: `Unable to start services. See log file for details.`

Log file:

```
2018-01-17T18:23:13.889+08:00| vthread-4| I125: Log for VMware Workstation pid=2798 version=12.5.7 build=build-5813279 option=Release
2018-01-17T18:23:13.889+08:00| vthread-4| I125: The process is 64-bit.
2018-01-17T18:23:13.889+08:00| vthread-4| I125: Host codepage=UTF-8 encoding=UTF-8
2018-01-17T18:23:13.889+08:00| vthread-4| I125: Host is Linux 4.13.0-26-generic Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
2018-01-17T18:23:13.889+08:00| vthread-4| I125: DictionaryLoad: Cannot open file "/usr/lib/vmware/settings": No such file or directory.
2018-01-17T18:23:13.889+08:00| vthread-4| I125: PREF Optional preferences file not found at /usr/lib/vmware/settings. Using default values.
2018-01-17T18:23:13.889+08:00| vthread-4| I125: DictionaryLoad: Cannot open file "/root/.vmware/config": No such file or directory.
2018-01-17T18:23:13.889+08:00| vthread-4| I125: PREF Optional preferences file not found at /root/.vmware/config. Using default values.
2018-01-17T18:23:13.889+08:00| vthread-4| I125: PREF Unable to check permissions for preferences file.
2018-01-17T18:23:13.889+08:00| vthread-4| I125: DictionaryLoad: Cannot open file "/root/.vmware/preferences": No such file or directory.
2018-01-17T18:23:13.889+08:00| vthread-4| I125: PREF Failed to load user preferences.
2018-01-17T18:23:13.926+08:00| vthread-4| W115: Logging to /tmp/vmware-root/vmware-2798.log
2018-01-17T18:23:13.936+08:00| vthread-4| I125: Obtaining info using the running kernel.
2018-01-17T18:23:13.936+08:00| vthread-4| I125: Created new pathsHash.
2018-01-17T18:23:13.936+08:00| vthread-4| I125: Setting header path for 4.13.0-26-generic to "/lib/modules/4.13.0-26-generic/build/include".
2018-01-17T18:23:13.936+08:00| vthread-4| I125: Validating path "/lib/modules/4.13.0-26-generic/build/include" for kernel release "4.13.0-26-generic".
2018-01-17T18:23:13.936+08:00| vthread-4| I125: Failed to find /lib/modules/4.13.0-26-generic/build/include/linux/version.h
2018-01-17T18:23:13.936+08:00| vthread-4| I125: /lib/modules/4.13.0-26-generic/build/include/linux/version.h not found, looking for generated/uapi/linux/version.h instead.
2018-01-17T18:23:13.936+08:00| vthread-4| I125: using /usr/bin/gcc for preprocess check
2018-01-17T18:23:13.940+08:00| vthread-4| I125: Preprocessed UTS_RELEASE, got value "4.13.0-26-generic".
2018-01-17T18:23:13.940+08:00| vthread-4| I125: The header path "/lib/modules/4.13.0-26-generic/build/include" for the kernel "4.13.0-26-generic" is valid.  Whoohoo!
2018-01-17T18:23:14.063+08:00| vthread-4| I125: found symbol version file /lib/modules/4.13.0-26-generic/build/Module.symvers
2018-01-17T18:23:14.063+08:00| vthread-4| I125: Reading symbol versions from /lib/modules/4.13.0-26-generic/build/Module.symvers.
2018-01-17T18:23:14.081+08:00| vthread-4| I125: Read 22181 symbol versions
2018-01-17T18:23:14.081+08:00| vthread-4| I125: Reading in info for the vmmon module.
2018-01-17T18:23:14.081+08:00| vthread-4| I125: Reading in info for the vmnet module.
2018-01-17T18:23:14.081+08:00| vthread-4| I125: Reading in info for the vmblock module.
2018-01-17T18:23:14.081+08:00| vthread-4| I125: Reading in info for the vmci module.
2018-01-17T18:23:14.081+08:00| vthread-4| I125: Reading in info for the vsock module.
2018-01-17T18:23:14.081+08:00| vthread-4| I125: Setting vsock to depend on vmci.
2018-01-17T18:23:14.081+08:00| vthread-4| I125: Invoking modinfo on "vmmon".
2018-01-17T18:23:14.083+08:00| vthread-4| I125: "/sbin/modinfo" exited with status 0.
2018-01-17T18:23:14.083+08:00| vthread-4| I125: Invoking modinfo on "vmnet".
2018-01-17T18:23:14.084+08:00| vthread-4| I125: "/sbin/modinfo" exited with status 256.
2018-01-17T18:23:14.084+08:00| vthread-4| I125: Invoking modinfo on "vmblock".
2018-01-17T18:23:14.085+08:00| vthread-4| I125: "/sbin/modinfo" exited with status 256.
2018-01-17T18:23:14.085+08:00| vthread-4| I125: Invoking modinfo on "vmci".
2018-01-17T18:23:14.086+08:00| vthread-4| I125: "/sbin/modinfo" exited with status 256.
2018-01-17T18:23:14.086+08:00| vthread-4| I125: Invoking modinfo on "vsock".
2018-01-17T18:23:14.087+08:00| vthread-4| I125: "/sbin/modinfo" exited with status 0.
2018-01-17T18:23:14.099+08:00| vthread-4| I125: to be installed: vmnet status: 0
2018-01-17T18:23:14.114+08:00| vthread-4| I125: Obtaining info using the running kernel.
2018-01-17T18:23:14.114+08:00| vthread-4| I125: Setting header path for 4.13.0-26-generic to "/lib/modules/4.13.0-26-generic/build/include".
2018-01-17T18:23:14.114+08:00| vthread-4| I125: Validating path "/lib/modules/4.13.0-26-generic/build/include" for kernel release "4.13.0-26-generic".
2018-01-17T18:23:14.114+08:00| vthread-4| I125: Failed to find /lib/modules/4.13.0-26-generic/build/include/linux/version.h
2018-01-17T18:23:14.114+08:00| vthread-4| I125: /lib/modules/4.13.0-26-generic/build/include/linux/version.h not found, looking for generated/uapi/linux/version.h instead.
2018-01-17T18:23:14.114+08:00| vthread-4| I125: using /usr/bin/gcc for preprocess check
2018-01-17T18:23:14.118+08:00| vthread-4| I125: Preprocessed UTS_RELEASE, got value "4.13.0-26-generic".
2018-01-17T18:23:14.118+08:00| vthread-4| I125: The header path "/lib/modules/4.13.0-26-generic/build/include" for the kernel "4.13.0-26-generic" is valid.  Whoohoo!
2018-01-17T18:23:14.240+08:00| vthread-4| I125: found symbol version file /lib/modules/4.13.0-26-generic/build/Module.symvers
2018-01-17T18:23:14.240+08:00| vthread-4| I125: Reading symbol versions from /lib/modules/4.13.0-26-generic/build/Module.symvers.
2018-01-17T18:23:14.257+08:00| vthread-4| I125: Read 22181 symbol versions
2018-01-17T18:23:14.257+08:00| vthread-4| I125: Kernel header path retrieved from FileEntry: /lib/modules/4.13.0-26-generic/build/include
2018-01-17T18:23:14.257+08:00| vthread-4| I125: Update kernel header path to /lib/modules/4.13.0-26-generic/build/include
2018-01-17T18:23:14.257+08:00| vthread-4| I125: Validating path "/lib/modules/4.13.0-26-generic/build/include" for kernel release "4.13.0-26-generic".
2018-01-17T18:23:14.257+08:00| vthread-4| I125: Failed to find /lib/modules/4.13.0-26-generic/build/include/linux/version.h
2018-01-17T18:23:14.257+08:00| vthread-4| I125: /lib/modules/4.13.0-26-generic/build/include/linux/version.h not found, looking for generated/uapi/linux/version.h instead.
2018-01-17T18:23:14.257+08:00| vthread-4| I125: using /usr/bin/gcc for preprocess check
2018-01-17T18:23:14.262+08:00| vthread-4| I125: Preprocessed UTS_RELEASE, got value "4.13.0-26-generic".
2018-01-17T18:23:14.262+08:00| vthread-4| I125: The header path "/lib/modules/4.13.0-26-generic/build/include" for the kernel "4.13.0-26-generic" is valid.  Whoohoo!
2018-01-17T18:23:14.262+08:00| vthread-4| I125: Found compiler at "/usr/bin/gcc"
2018-01-17T18:23:14.264+08:00| vthread-4| I125: Got gcc version "5.4.0".
2018-01-17T18:23:14.264+08:00| vthread-4| I125: The GCC version matches the kernel GCC minor version like a glove.
2018-01-17T18:23:14.264+08:00| vthread-4| I125: Using user supplied compiler "/usr/bin/gcc".
2018-01-17T18:23:14.266+08:00| vthread-4| I125: Got gcc version "5.4.0".
2018-01-17T18:23:14.266+08:00| vthread-4| I125: The GCC version matches the kernel GCC minor version like a glove.
2018-01-17T18:23:14.267+08:00| vthread-4| I125: Trying to find a suitable PBM set for kernel "4.13.0-26-generic".
2018-01-17T18:23:14.267+08:00| vthread-4| I125: No matching PBM set was found for kernel "4.13.0-26-generic".
2018-01-17T18:23:14.267+08:00| vthread-4| I125: The GCC version matches the kernel GCC minor version like a glove.
2018-01-17T18:23:14.267+08:00| vthread-4| I125: Validating path "/lib/modules/4.13.0-26-generic/build/include" for kernel release "4.13.0-26-generic".
2018-01-17T18:23:14.267+08:00| vthread-4| I125: Failed to find /lib/modules/4.13.0-26-generic/build/include/linux/version.h
2018-01-17T18:23:14.267+08:00| vthread-4| I125: /lib/modules/4.13.0-26-generic/build/include/linux/version.h not found, looking for generated/uapi/linux/version.h instead.
2018-01-17T18:23:14.267+08:00| vthread-4| I125: using /usr/bin/gcc for preprocess check
2018-01-17T18:23:14.271+08:00| vthread-4| I125: Preprocessed UTS_RELEASE, got value "4.13.0-26-generic".
2018-01-17T18:23:14.271+08:00| vthread-4| I125: The header path "/lib/modules/4.13.0-26-generic/build/include" for the kernel "4.13.0-26-generic" is valid.  Whoohoo!
2018-01-17T18:23:14.274+08:00| vthread-4| I125: The GCC version matches the kernel GCC minor version like a glove.
2018-01-17T18:23:14.274+08:00| vthread-4| I125: Validating path "/lib/modules/4.13.0-26-generic/build/include" for kernel release "4.13.0-26-generic".
2018-01-17T18:23:14.274+08:00| vthread-4| I125: Failed to find /lib/modules/4.13.0-26-generic/build/include/linux/version.h
2018-01-17T18:23:14.274+08:00| vthread-4| I125: /lib/modules/4.13.0-26-generic/build/include/linux/version.h not found, looking for generated/uapi/linux/version.h instead.
2018-01-17T18:23:14.274+08:00| vthread-4| I125: using /usr/bin/gcc for preprocess check
2018-01-17T18:23:14.278+08:00| vthread-4| I125: Preprocessed UTS_RELEASE, got value "4.13.0-26-generic".
2018-01-17T18:23:14.278+08:00| vthread-4| I125: The header path "/lib/modules/4.13.0-26-generic/build/include" for the kernel "4.13.0-26-generic" is valid.  Whoohoo!
2018-01-17T18:23:14.278+08:00| vthread-4| I125: Using temp dir "/tmp".
2018-01-17T18:23:14.279+08:00| vthread-4| I125: Obtaining info using the running kernel.
2018-01-17T18:23:14.279+08:00| vthread-4| I125: Setting header path for 4.13.0-26-generic to "/lib/modules/4.13.0-26-generic/build/include".
2018-01-17T18:23:14.279+08:00| vthread-4| I125: Validating path "/lib/modules/4.13.0-26-generic/build/include" for kernel release "4.13.0-26-generic".
2018-01-17T18:23:14.279+08:00| vthread-4| I125: Failed to find /lib/modules/4.13.0-26-generic/build/include/linux/version.h
2018-01-17T18:23:14.279+08:00| vthread-4| I125: /lib/modules/4.13.0-26-generic/build/include/linux/version.h not found, looking for generated/uapi/linux/version.h instead.
2018-01-17T18:23:14.279+08:00| vthread-4| I125: using /usr/bin/gcc for preprocess check
2018-01-17T18:23:14.284+08:00| vthread-4| I125: Preprocessed UTS_RELEASE, got value "4.13.0-26-generic".
2018-01-17T18:23:14.284+08:00| vthread-4| I125: The header path "/lib/modules/4.13.0-26-generic/build/include" for the kernel "4.13.0-26-generic" is valid.  Whoohoo!
2018-01-17T18:23:14.403+08:00| vthread-4| I125: found symbol version file /lib/modules/4.13.0-26-generic/build/Module.symvers
2018-01-17T18:23:14.403+08:00| vthread-4| I125: Reading symbol versions from /lib/modules/4.13.0-26-generic/build/Module.symvers.
2018-01-17T18:23:14.420+08:00| vthread-4| I125: Read 22181 symbol versions
2018-01-17T18:23:14.420+08:00| vthread-4| I125: Invoking modinfo on "vmnet".
2018-01-17T18:23:14.421+08:00| vthread-4| I125: "/sbin/modinfo" exited with status 256.
2018-01-17T18:23:14.905+08:00| vthread-4| I125: Setting destination path for vmnet to "/lib/modules/4.13.0-26-generic/misc/vmnet.ko".
2018-01-17T18:23:14.905+08:00| vthread-4| I125: Extracting the vmnet source from "/usr/lib/vmware/modules/source/vmnet.tar".
2018-01-17T18:23:14.915+08:00| vthread-4| I125: Successfully extracted the vmnet source.
2018-01-17T18:23:14.915+08:00| vthread-4| I125: Building module with command "/usr/bin/make -j4 -C /tmp/modconfig-GriQK1/vmnet-only auto-build HEADER_DIR=/lib/modules/4.13.0-26-generic/build/include CC=/usr/bin/gcc IS_GCC_3=no"
2018-01-17T18:23:17.135+08:00| vthread-4| W115: Failed to build vmnet.  Failed to execute the build command.
```

System information:

```
Linux 4.13.0-26-generic #29~16.04.2-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jan 9 22:00:44 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

VMware Player Version:

```
VMware Player 12.5.7 build-5813279
```

Comment: How did you install VMware Player? In which version? Please [edit] your post, when you want to clarify something or add information? It’s best to have everything relevant in one place. Additionally, comments may be deleted for various reasons. Thanks.

Comment: @DavidFoerster thanks for reminding, version information added

Comment: Thanks for the version info. Could you please also explain how you installed VMWare Player?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by upgrading the VMWare player to the latest version.

1. [Download VMware Workstation Player 14 from official website](https://www.vmware.com/products/workstation-player/workstation-player-evaluation.html)
2. Make the .bundle file executable

   ```
   sudo chmod a+x VMware-Player-14.0.0-6661328.x86_64.bundle
   ```
3. Run the installer

   ```
   sudo ./VMware-Player-14.0.0-6661328.x86_64.bundle
   ```

Comment: I recommend to [edit] this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on Ask Ubuntu.)